# Using SUMIFS in Excel-vba to check multiple conditions

Tags: vba, excel, sumifs, multiple-conditions

I have just started using `SUMIFS` in vba and I need to check multiple conditions. It should check if something matches either of these AA, AT, AB, AC, AN, AR, AD

I have this code so far which works for only one condition.

```
WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(TotQty, Style, CellVal, TotQty, ">0", Location, "AA")
```

Any idea how to adjust it to search for all other options?

Comment: SUMIFS only sums if ALL conditions are met,  You should use the OR function instead

Comment: can i use the or function within the sumifs or should i completely get rid of sumifs and put it as a or?       WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(TotQty, Style, CellVal, TotQty, ">0", Location, OR("AA","AT","AB","AC",AN","AR","AD")

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do something like:

```
MsgBox [Sum(SumIfs(TotQty, Style, CellVal, TotQty, ">0", Location, {"AA","AT","AB","AC","AN","AR","AD"}))]
```

or

```
MsgBox Evaluate("=SUM(SumIfs(TotQty, Style, CellVal, TotQty, "">0"", Location, {""AA"",""AT"",""AB"",""AC"",""AN"",""AR"",""AD""}))")
```